Error initializing the from_config() function in teh embedchain package
I am facing an issue in initializing the from_config() function of embedchain package:
Here is my code:
from embedchain import App
from openai import OpenAI
import yaml

def initialize_bots(config_filename='config.json'):
    global news_bot, email_bot, link_inserter_bot, image_inserter_bot, article_bot

    # Load the JSON configuration directly
    
    # Determine the base directory based on whether the script is running as a standalone executable or as a script
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # Running as an executable
        base_directory = sys._MEIPASS  # Temporary folder where the executable's data is unpacked
    else:
        # Running as a script
        base_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        
    config_file_path = os.path.join(base_directory, config_filename)
    
    # Debug statement:
    if os.path.exists(config_file_path):
        print(f"{config_filename} is present in the base directory.")
    else:
        print(f"{config_filename} is NOT present in the base directory.")

    # Check if the configuration file exists
    if not os.path.exists(config_file_path):
        raise FileNotFoundError(f"The configuration file {config_file_path} does not exist.")
    
    # Load the configuration file
    with open(config_file_path, 'r') as file:
        config_data = json.load(file)

    # Retrieve models and selected option from the configuration
    models = config_data.get('Models', {}).get('models', None)
    selected_option = config_data.get('Settings', {}).get('selected_ai_option', None)

    # Ensure models is not None
    if models is None:
        raise ValueError("Models configuration is missing or incorrectly set in the configuration file.")

    # Initialize news_bot
    config_path = os.path.join(base_directory, 'config', 'openai.yaml')
    
    # -------- Debug statement -------------
    
    # Debug statement:
    if os.path.exists(config_path):
        print(f"{config_path} is present in the base directory. 1010101010101010 ")
    else:
        print(f"{config_path} is NOT present in the base directory. 1010101010101010 ")
    
    # -------- Debug statement ------------
    
    
    if not os.path.exists(config_path):
        raise FileNotFoundError(f"The configuration file {config_path} does not exist.")
    
    # (1) News bot
    try:
        
        with open(config_path, 'r') as file:
            news_bot_data = yaml.safe_load(file)
            
            print("news_bot_data:                      ", news_bot_data)
        
        news_bot = App.from_config(config = news_bot_data)  # Error loading Bots in Exe (embedchain)
        print("What is inside the News Bot:                                     ", news_bot)
    except Exception as e:
        error_info = traceback.print_exc()
        print("something went wrong when loading the news bot. Exception is:    ", e)
        print("something went wrong and error info:    ", error_info)
        print("What is inside the News Bot:                                     ", news_bot)

    # (2) Initialize email_bot
    try:
        
        with open(os.path.join(base_directory, "config", "email_openai.yaml"), 'r') as file:

            email_bot_data = yaml.safe_load(file)
            
            print("email_bot_data:                      ", email_bot_data)
            
        email_bot = App.from_config(config = email_bot_data)
        print("What is inside the Email Bot:                                     ", email_bot)
    except Exception as e:
        error_info = traceback.print_exc()
        print("something went wrong when loading the Email bot. Exception is:    ", e)
        print("something went wrong and error info:    ", error_info)

        print("What is inside the Email Bot:                                     ", email_bot)
        
    # (3) Initialize link_inserter_bot
    try:
        
        with open(os.path.join(base_directory, "config", "link_inserter_openai.yaml"), 'r') as file:

            link_insertion_bot_data = yaml.safe_load(file)
            
            print("link_insertion_bot_data:                     ", link_insertion_bot_data)
        
        link_inserter_bot = App.from_config(config = link_insertion_bot_data)
        print("What is inside the Link Inserted Bot:                                     ", link_inserter_bot)
    except Exception as e:
        error_info = traceback.print_exc()
        print("something went wrong when loading the link_inserter_bot Exception is:    ", e)
        print("something went wrong and error info:    ", error_info)

        
        print("What is inside the link inserter bot:                                     ", link_inserter_bot)
        
    # (4) Initialize image_inserter_bot
    try:
        
        with open(os.path.join(base_directory, "config", "image_insertion_openai_gpt-4o.yaml"), 'r') as file:
            image_insrtion_bot_data = yaml.safe_load(file)
            print("image_insrtion_bot_data:                     ", image_insrtion_bot_data)
        
        image_inserter_bot = App.from_config(config = image_insrtion_bot_data)
    except Exception as e:
        
        error_info = traceback.print_exc()
        
        print("something went wrong when loading the image_inserter_bot Exception is:    ", e)
        print("something went wrong and error info:    ", error_info)
        print("What is inside the image inserter bot:                                     ", image_inserter_bot)
        
    # Reset article_bot
    article_bot = None

    # Iterate through models to find the selected option
    
    for model in models:
        if selected_option == model:
            config_file = f"article_writer_{model.lower().replace(' ', '_')}.yaml"
            config_path = os.path.join(base_directory, 'config', config_file)

            if not os.path.exists(config_path):
                raise FileNotFoundError(f"The configuration file {config_path} does not exist.")

            article_bot = App.from_config(config_path)
            break

    if article_bot is None:
        print("No Model Selected")
 

Code is working fine in my local setup.
I am using pyinstaller to create .exe. But I am getting error:
Multiplexed path must contain at least one pah.
Here is my console:
Multiplexed path must contain at least one path.
Error in this line
news_bot = App.from_config(config = news_bot_data)
In this function where i am using from_config() i am getting error in all these line. config data is loaded correctly. I dont know why still same error
I tried to load all bots in my code using from_config() function. But recieving error that i have mentioned
